# UpdateOne returns a mongoose object and not document

Tags: mongoose

When running this query:

```
  const project = await models.Projects
    .updateOne(
      { _id: projectId },
      {
        $addToSet:
        {
          membersIds:
          {
            $each: membersIds
          },
        },
      },
    );
```

The response I get is the follwoing:

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

Is it possible to get an updated object instead of this mongoose data?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne): `[callback] «Function» params are (error, writeOpResult)` which means that there's no way to return a document with `updateOne` method.

Instead of `updateOne` it's however possible to use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) providing `lean: true` option

Answer (score 16):

ATTENTION !

I saw the responses, they are all right, **BUT**, pay attention to add the ***new*** option and to set it as true into the query to get the new updated document, otherwise it will return back the document before updating:

```
    models.Projects.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { "_id": projectId }, 
    { $addToSet:{ membersIds: { $each: membersIds }}})
   .exec()
   .then((response) => {
          console.log('document before updating =>', response);
        });

    models.Projects.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { "_id": projectId }, 
        { $addToSet:{ membersIds: { $each: membersIds }}}, 
        {new: true})
       .exec()
       .then((response) => {
              console.log('document after updating =>', response);
            });
```

Comment: In latest versions of MongoDB you should use { returnDocument: 'after' } instead of { new: true }

Comment: Last version of MongoDB or mongoose ?

Comment: In mongo shell its { returnNewDocument: boolean }, in mongoose (and i guess in node.js mongo driver too) its { returnDocument: 'after' }. Tested on findOneAndUpdate.

Answer (score 6):

If you won't use document after update operation, you should use **updateOne**, it is faster. However; if you need updated document, you should use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) or [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). You can filter just with _id with **findByIdAndUpdate** but you can use every exist fields filter with **findOneAndUpdate**.

Comment: Short and accurate! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `findByIdAndUpdate` to get an updated document. So, from your code, just change to this:

```
const project = await models.Projects.findByIdAndUpdate(
  {_id: projectId},
  {
    $addToSet:
    {
      membersIds:
      {
        $each: membersIds
      },
    },
  },
  {new: true}
)
```

Do not forget to add an options `{new: true}`, which return updated document back to your project variable.